# Entity Framework Rounding

Tags: entity-framework-4

One of my entity objects (EF4) has a property that is a decimal.  The field in the database is Decimal(18,2)

If I set the value to 30.4777  it only sends 30.47 over to the db in the insert statement (as confirmed by the tracer).  Is there a way to get it to send 30.4777 and then just let the database round it off (which it seems happy to otherwise do)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `Precision` and `Scale` properties of your decimal field yourself. Just right-click the property in the designer, and choose `Properties`. In the properties window you will find `Precision` and `Scale`. Set `Scale` to 4 and try your queries again.

Comment: He already had precision set and wanted to know how to get it to round instead of truncate. Is this normal for EF to truncate rather than round???

Comment: Yes it is normal EF behaviour to truncate (as stupid as it seems) see http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/735

Comment: If you update the precision or scale in the EDMX model to be different to the database, this change will be wiped out (i.e. reset) if anyone runs the "Update model from database..." command in the future.

Comment: Hey neat!  I am using EF 5 and I don't have those options!

Comment: use this and set it at startup or when a EF context is built out:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlproviderservices.truncatedecimalstoscale(v=vs.113).aspx